# Remove specific and special characters from a String using bash/sh script

Tags: string, bash, replace, sh, special-characters

```
myVar = designers/Atom-CMP-d0b3695.zip
```

only part of this string needs to be extracted from the above variable.

```
myDesiredVar = CMP-d0b3695
```

I have tried several approach but still can't find an appropriate way to solve this issue? Any quick help would be really apppreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` string manipulation:

```
s='myVar = designers/Atom-CMP-d0b3695.zip'
r="${s%.*}"
r="${r#*-}"
```

**Output:**

```
echo "$r"
CMP-d0b3695
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myVar=designers/Atom-CMP-d0b3695.zip

myDesiredVar=$(echo "$myVar" |grep -oP '\-\K[^.]+')

echo $myDesiredVar
CMP-d0b3695
```

Using `grep` with `perl regex`: `\K` is for the positive look behind. and `[^.]+` means, anything till literal dot is seen.

`var=$(command....)` this is known as command substitution. Hope now the dump is useful.

Comment: Please explain your answer if possible rather than just dumping in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** solution:

```
res=$(sed 's/^[^-]*-\([^.]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$myVar")
echo $res
CMP-d0b3695
```